# how to add java 14 in websphere app server(WAS)

Tags: java, websphere

i want to update to java 14 on websphere based on a requirement of client but can only find upto java 8. is there a way to externally add it or anything as such to update it to jav 14

Answer (score 1):

"WebSphere" can refer to a product or one of the runtimes available in that product.

WebSphere contains two EE runtimes, WebSphere Liberty and the older WebSphere Application Server traditional.

- WebSphere Liberty supports Java 17, but not 14.
- WebSphere Application Server traditional doesn't support anything after Java 8.

Your best bet is to run the code requiring Java 14 or later on WebSphere Liberty with Java 17.  Java 14 is a non-LTS release and is already out of standard and premier support.